# How to delete a single (SSL root) certificate?

Tags: certificates

There is only a way to purge the whole certificate store (for SSL root certificates like those used for 802.1x).

Is there an app, setting or (as a last resort) command line to remove a single certificate?

(Android 2.2)

Comment: Related question: where are certificates stored in the Android OS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove trusted CAs on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-can-i-remove-trusted-cas-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I had never removed a cert before but I've added my own and it looks like it's the same process.

It's basically:

- use Linux (or a vm of Linux)
- install bouncycastle (java SSL library)
- download the cacerts.bks files from the device
- use keytool -delete command to remove the cert from cacerts.bks
- verify that it worked with keytool
- push the cacerts.bks file back up to the device

Bouncy Castle: http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html
Detailed instructions on how to use keytool: http://wiki.cacert.org/ImportRootCert#Android_Phones

In ubuntu it's a little easier to download through apt just so you can get the PATH stuff right. "apt-cache search bouncycastle" should help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on 2.2, root your device, then use CACertMan:

[Market Link](https://market.android.com/details?id=info.guardianproject.cacert) [Source Code](https://github.com/guardianproject/cacert)

You can choose to delete certificates one-by-one, and back up your configuration for use later.