# How can I remove trusted CAs on Android?

Tags: security, certificates

From the [current fallout](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&btnmeta_news_search=1&q=diginotar) around DigiNotar (in short, a Root Certificate Authority that has been hacked, fake HTTPS certificates issued, MITM attacks very likely), there are some parts concerning Android ([see yesterday's interim report in PDF](http://www.rijksoverheid.nl/bestanden/documenten-en-publicaties/rapporten/2011/09/05/fox-it-operation-black-tulip/rapport-fox-it-operation-black-tulip-v1-0.pdf)):

- fraudulent certificates for *.android.com has been generated (which would include market.android.com)
- there may be other such fraudulent certificates signed by this CA in the wild (currently nobody knows for sure, one way or the other)
- this could happen to another CA in the future (Comodo had a similar problem a few months ago)

So, how do I remove a CA I no longer trust from my Android phone? (I have root and CM6 on my specific phone, if that's relevant)

Comment: CM team are working on a fix according to https://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=4260

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookout Mobile has blogged about this due to the DigiNotar events, and provided some pretty good (read: lengthy) instructions which you can find [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111125212719/http://blog.mylookout.com:80/2011/08/for-rooted-android-device-users-open-heart-surgery-on-your-android-ca-store).

The gist of it is that you need to pull `/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks` and then remove the CAs from the store, then push the store back to the device and reboot. Their instructions require that you have [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) (for decrypting the store), root access, and a working adb connection. I'm not sure if this applies to all versions of Android or not, but my guess would be that the location of the CA store hasn't changed in quite some time (if ever).

Comment: In your list of requirements of important entry for some devices is missing: You need an unprotected system partition (also known as "S-OFF"). If an S-ON system the command "adb remount" will not work.

Answer (score 19):

In Android Lollipop 5.0
Settings → Security →  Trusted credentials →  *User* tab →  Select your certificate →  Scroll down, Click on *Remove* button →    *Done*.

Comment: Good to know if you're on a recent Android version, thanks. (I understand this is a feature introduced in 5.0, correct?)

Comment: It's a shame how this is implemented. Distrusting all CAs I don't deem trustworthy (why should I trust some random Chinese/Turkish/SouthAmerican company?) takes about 1 1/2 hours of clicking and scrolling. Tedious to say the least. On the other hand installing my own trusted credentials is nearly impossible.

Comment: On Android 8.0, this moved to Settings → Security & Location → _Encryption & credentials_ → Trusted credentials

Answer (score 2):

lock screen and security.
other security settings.
view security certificates.
users.

Then remove it.

S7 Edge 2016-07-14

Comment: What Android version is this?

Comment: You might want to include screenshots - makes it easier for most users to follow the instructions :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove them one at a time. Typically there is a large number so researching each one is impossible. Just disabling them one of the time takes a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the name of the credential, scroll down and then press turn off.

Comment: I think you meant "Disable" instead of "turn off". However, please also indicate the Android version and brand since not all version have this feature.

Comment: I think this would be in "System settings > Security > Trusted Credentials". At least this is on my Android 4.1.2.