# What Trusted Root CAs are included in Android by default?

Tags: security, certificates, https

There doesn't seem to be a central Android resource that lists the Trusted Root CAs included in the OS or default browser ([related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665588/android-list-of-available-trusted-root-certificates)), so how can I find out which are included on my phone by default?

With the number of root certificates that have been compromised, and the number of fraudulent SSL certs created over the last couple of years, this is an issue for anyone relying on SSL for security, as otherwise you won't know if you want to [remove any trusted CAs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-can-i-remove-trusted-cas-on-android).

*(not listing my manufacturer or OS version as I'm looking for a generic resource or solution that should be applicable to any device)*

Comment: I have used this app (root required) to list and delete individual root certs: [CACertMan](http://f-droid.org/forums/topic/cacertman/) or on [Play Store](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/hardware-gps-fix-for-the-galaxy-s-i9000-and-i9001/). The guradian project also maintains an edited version of the standard keystore: https://github.com/guardianproject/cacert

Comment: Play Store link in previous comment is wrong - Here's the right one [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.cacert&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd)

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the hint, seems I messed up with my copy/paste buffer (leaving the comment, as you and eldarerathis both provided the correct one)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On ICS or later [you can check this in your settings](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/ics-trust-store-implementation.html). Go to `Settings->Security->Trusted Credentials` to see a list of all your trusted CAs, separated by whether they were included with the system or installed by the user.

Earlier versions of Android keep their certs under `/system/etc/security` in an encrypted bundle named `cacerts.bks` which you can [extract using Bouncy Castle](http://blog.mylookout.com/blog/2011/08/31/for-rooted-android-device-users-open-heart-surgery-on-your-android-ca-store/) and the `keytool` program. The summary is to first pull the bundle using `adb` (you need a root shell) then you can use Bouncy Castle to list the contents of the bundle:

```
shell~$ adb pull /system/etc/security/cacerts.bks`
shell~$ keytool -keystore cacerts.bks -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -storepass changeit -v -list
```

There's also at least one app that you can try if you'd prefer not to use the shell: [CACertMan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.cacert) (requires root to modify the list, but should allow you to view the list without root). I believe it came about due to the DigiNotar fiasco since there were no particularly easy ways for a user to revoke the cert at the time. Since the certs are stored differently on ICS and later this app will only work on devices running Gingerbread (or earlier), but it is obsolete on ICS/JB anyway.

Comment: Yep, it came because of DigiNotar. Root is only required for editing CAs out (e.g. Chinese state CAs), not for viewing I suppose (IIRC).

Comment: @ce4: I don't recall if you need root just to browse with CACertMan or not - I'll check that real quick. Update: Think you're right, I can list them if I deny it root access, I just can't save a modified list. I'll clarify that.

Comment: Is there a (rooted) way to edit/add certificates from the shell?  The Settings method claims success on my tablet, but the certificates aren't actually installed.